relation of rules in stylistic/eslint-plugin-js and stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts
In the package @stylistic, there's two plugins eslint-plugin-js and eslint-plugin-js.
There's some similar rules in the two plugins. For instance, no-extra-parens for js and ts respectively.
I am using eslint 9 flat config. In my ts project, I had a combination of many config sharables from the internet, includes the previously mentioned two sharalbes. So, do I need to disable all rules in eslint-plugin-js and then enable rules in eslint-plugin-js? Or ts rules will, if it comes in the end, automatically override rules in js?
